# Network manager ignoring manually created system-connections file

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

I'm trying to make an image for a device that includes a NetworkManager connection for an LTE modem.

I've created a config file for the connection:

```
[connection]
id=modem
uuid=4b5f7f0b-1c58-4fa3-bc3c-45a3e3d329d8
type=gsm
interface-name=ttyACM0
permissions=

[gsm]
apn=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
number=XXXXXXXXXXXXxx

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

and placed this at  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/modem which is what the normal nmcli con add command would do. However when booting up this image, NetworkManager shows no connections:

```
root@bionic-armhf:~# nmcli c show
NAME  UUID  TYPE  DEVICE
```

I've also tried restarting the service.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a way to do this without manually creating the connection or creating it via a startup script? Ideally it would be done all through config files.

Comment: `permissions` shouldn't be empty.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the input. So interestingly, this file I've pasted here is what is generated by nmcli con add. If i run that command to generate this file on the deployed system, it knows about the connection even though permissions is empty.

Comment: Did you restart NM?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes. Actually your previous point about permissions helped me in a different way. I forgot to set the file permissions for the file properly which seems to be the cause of the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon further examination, I had forgotten to set the file permissions properly.

`chmod 600 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/modem`

Fixed the issue I was having. I just made the perms match what nmcli con add creates by default.

Note that the owner and group of the file must also be set to `root`, and you must reissue a `nmcli conn reload` after adding a file or fixing permissions. You can see the currently loaded definitions using `nmcli conn show`.